# Unable to send files to slack from R using slackrUpload

Tags: r, slack-api, slack

I am trying to use `slackr` package to push messages and files from R to slack.

I am able to send messages successfully using `slackr`, but have been unable to get the function `slackrUpload` working. Any suggestions would be appreciated

I first set up an incoming webhook in slack. I was then able to get the below working (this sends "Test message" to the channel "solutions":

```
> library(slackr)

> slackrSetup(channel = "#solutions",
              icon_emoji = ":information_source:",
              incoming_webhook_url ="https://hooks.slack.com/services/T.../B.../I...",
              api_token = "...-...-...")

> slackr("Test message")
```

...but when I try to use `slackrUpload` the function errors:

```
> html_file <- "url_path/checks.html"

> slackrUpload(filename = html_file)
```

Error returned:

```
Error in data.frame(id = x$id, name = x$name, real_name = x$real_name) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

(I have tested that the path to the html is correct)

R Session information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 RC (2015-06-10 r68509)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] slackr_1.2       ggplot2_2.1.0    data.table_1.9.6 jsonlite_0.9.19  httr_1.1.0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.4.0     plyr_1.8.3       R6_2.1.2         tools_3.2.1      gtable_0.2.0     curl_0.9.6       Rcpp_0.12.3      grid_3.2.1       chron_2.3-47     munsell_0.4.3
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a [common issue](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/slackr/issues/5) with old versions of `slackr`. Upgrading to at least 1.2.3 should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used `devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/slackr")` to move package version from 1.2 to 1.4.1.9000 (`packageVersion("slackr")`) but this latest version doesn't even push messages from slack to r?